# What exactly classified as adhoc queries segment of the server dashboard report?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at a standard report -> server dashboard.

More than 50% of the pie chart is classified as adhoc query.

What exactly classified as adhoc queries segment of the server dashboard report?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else your dashboard shows other than adhoc queries, check if [this](https://devjef.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/comparison-ad-hoc-vs-stored-procedure-vs-dynamic-sql/) clarifies your question.

Comment: Does it mean adhoc as in the sense of queries fired once in a while?

Comment: @variable not necessarily, it depends on application requirements and that could happen frequently too. Not all adhoc workloads are bad but I prefer stored procedures over adhoc workloads because of the better reuse of cached execution plans and other security benefits they offer.